# RN Error in file importing

Tags: import, react-native

I encountered a file import problem with react native, initially I thought there may be a special file system manager for react native, but when I factored out my styles into a separate application.js file and imported it, it worked fine, however, when I tried to import my root.jsx it throws this error,

```
'Unable to resolve module ./react/components/root.jsx from
/Users/******/Desktop/Kaffeinate/index.ios.js: Directory
/Users/******/Desktop/Kaffeinate/react/components/root.jsx doesnt exist'
```

I have tried restarting xcode and atom but to no avail.

here's my index.ios.js,

[image: index.ios.js]

and here's my root.jsx,

```
import React from 'react';
// import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
// import App from './app.jsx';
// import configureStore from '../store/store.js';
import {
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

export default class Root extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          Inside App.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `'./components/root.jsx'` or even  `'./components/root'` ?

Comment: @NaderDabit Yes I have tried both, combinations of moving the components folder out of the react folder and with or without .jsx